# Excel VBA Reformat Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data that will always be 8 columns (A-H) the number of rows could be different every time (Dynamic).

If the string in column A ends with:
"IT", "LN" or "SJ" then the row value in Column G needs to be divided by 100.

If the string ends in "KK" the value in Column G needs to be
divided by 1000.

Otherwise no math operation to the row needs to be performed.

The data also needs to be sorted alphabetically by column C then by column H.

After this is done the header row (1). Can be deleted.

What I have so far "works" but it results in a very long list of 0.0000 values in column G that makes copying out the cleaned data difficult.

Would anyone be able to show me a more efficient solution?

```
 Sub Clean()

 Dim wkb As Workbook

 Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook

 Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet


Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("H2:H2500" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
    
    
With ws.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:H2500")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With



Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(OR(RIGHT(RC[-8],2) = ""SJ"", RIGHT(RC[-8],2) = ""LN"", RIGHT(RC[-8],2) = ""IT"", RIGHT(RC[-8],2) = ""KK""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-8],2) = ""KK"",RC[-2]/1000,RC[-2]/100),RC[-2])"
Range("I2").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("I2500").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Range("I3:I2500").Select
Range("I2500").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("G2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0000"

  Columns("I").Delete


 Dim strDataRange As Range
 Dim keyRange As Range

 Set strDataRange = Range("A:H")
 Set keyRange = Range("C1")
 strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Header:=xlYes
 Rows(1).Delete

 End sub
```

Sample Input Data

| Codes | Population | Animal | Type | Size | Housing Qty | Average Cost | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SHIB IT | 4,504 | DOGE | Standard | SMALL | 15,019 | 9.5557 | JP |
| CORG LN | 33,052 | DOGE | Standard | SMALL | 8,816 | 31,404.9100 | FR |
| SOG SJ | 1,417 | CAT | Standard | BIG | 90 | 247.2508 | ZM |
| CHOW KK | 873 | DOGE | Standard | BIG | 9,192 | 177.2797 | CN |
| FLOP AG | 991 | CAT | Standard | BIG | 7 | 597.0650 | BZ |

Desired Output Data:
[image]

Comment: It would help if you posted your data as a table or at least included column headers.

Comment: Be careful: Once you divided your data in G, you will lose the original value. If you run for some reasons the macro again, you will divide the already divided amount another time, resulting in invalid data. If I where you, I would keep the original data in a (hidden) column.

Comment: Yes I noticed that issue as well. I think my end goal is to copy over the data to a separate workbook after the macro is run so hopefully that issue is avoided.

Comment: @SJR updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It copies everything to a new sheet so you don't lose the original data. Could be sped up if you have lots of data.

```
Sub x()

Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long

Set ws = Worksheets.Add

Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy ws.Range("A1") 'assumes data on sheet1 (code name, change to suit)

For r = 2 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Select Case Right(ws.Cells(r, 1), 2)
        Case "IT", "LN", "SJ": ws.Cells(r, "G").Value = ws.Cells(r, "G").Value / 100
        Case "KK": ws.Cells(r, "G").Value = ws.Cells(r, "G").Value / 1000
    End Select
Next r

With ws.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("H2:H" & ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range("A1:H" & ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! I was having an issue with my clipboard grabbing some random data when running this, but changing sheet1.Range to Sheets("Sheet1").Range fixed the issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also wanted to just thank you for teaching me the CurrentRegion function in VBA. This is going to be incredibly useful for me going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next compact and fast code. It will place the range to be processed in an array and drop down the processed result at the end. Now it returns overwriting the existing range. It can be easily adapted to return in another sheet:

```
Sub processRangeAH()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng = sh.Range("A1:H" & lastR)
 rng.Sort Key1:=sh.Range("H1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
 arr = rng.Value2
 
 For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    Select Case UCase(Right(arr(i, 1), 2))
        Case "IT", "LN", "SJ": arr(i, 7) = arr(i, 7) / 100
        Case "KK": arr(i, 7) = arr(i, 7) / 1000
    End Select
 Next i
 
 rng.Value2 = arr
 rng.Sort Key1:=sh.Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
 sh.Range("G2:G" & lastR).NumberFormat = "0.0000"
 sh.rows(1).Delete
End Sub
```

I posted this answer some hours before, when I left my office, but by mistake, in another thread...

Just to see how an array can be used, in order to increase the speed for larger range.

Comment: Thanks Fane! Il check this out as well. Sometimes these lists of data can get long so using an array sounds like a speedy solution. Thanks again!